# How to initialize Meta Audience Adapter in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, facebook-audience-network

i want to use Meta (Facebook) Audience Network bidding inside my app with Google Admob , i have done all that was written in documentation , but the problem is when i test the bidding with AdMob's test suite i see this error ..

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sPaD.jpg)

these are my dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.12.0.0'
```

and this is in Main Activity

```
  @Override
    public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        Map<String, AdapterStatus> statusMap = initializationStatus.getAdapterStatusMap();
        for (String adapterClass : statusMap.keySet()) {
            AdapterStatus status = statusMap.get(adapterClass);
            Log.d("MyApp", String.format(
                    "Adapter name: %s, Description: %s, Latency: %d",
                    adapterClass, status.getDescription(), status.getLatency()));
        }

        MediationTestSuite.launch(MainActivity.this);

    }
});
```

can you please tell me where am i wrong ?

i have tried to changing version code of both facebook and admob's sdk, but not works

Answer (score 2):

To initialize Facebook Audience Network SDK you can add this line inside your MainActivity

```
AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
```

Also, if you are Using FB in bidding with Admob Make sure either you add this line after Admob is initialized code or inside the Admob SDk's onInitializationComplete block of code like this

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus){
                       //Init the FAN SDK when Admob Mobile Ads SDK init Successfully
                        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. It in now showing adapter initialized. From where did u get the solution?

Comment: @AndroidDev Don't remember exactly but i read somewhere in some documentation that if you are doing mediation with any network then make sure all adapters are initialized for making a ad request.

So I found the code on FB Documentation to Initialize the FB Audience Network.

Comment: For me not showing Meta Audience, When i run, Log.d("MyApp" @TechyRakshak